# autocompletion for sublime text 3 package anaconda is slow

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I have my anaconda package installed with package installer for Sublime Text 3. The autocompletion feature takes ~ 2-4 seconds after "." to show available options. Has anyone encountered this, if so can you please advise if there is a method to correct this?

I am using a MAC for reference. Thanks!

Comment: Close voters: From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), software questions are allowed if if they cover "*[...] software tools commonly used by programmers*". Sublime Text, like vim, emacs, Notepad++, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext2+or+sublimetext3+or+sublimetext+or+vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+notepad%2b%2b) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your user preferences (**`Sublime Text → Preferences → Settings—User`**) and add the following to the top, just after the opening `{`:

```
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source"
    }
],
```

then save the file and restart Sublime (so that Anaconda reloads and sees the new settings). This should now trigger autocomplete as soon as you hit `.`. You can also try adding:

```
"auto_complete_delay": 0,
```

to instantly trigger autocomplete, but I find the default value of 50 (milliseconds) is fine.

Comment: I implemented the above. `csv_file = pd.read_csv(file_path, low_memory=False, index_col = 0)` and when I do `csv_file.` options do show up now, which is great. Following that line I have `subset_data = csv_file.sample(10, replace=False)` but when I do `subset_data.` no autocompletion options show. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @user5374436 it's possible Anaconda can't determine the return type of `csv_file.sample()`, and so doesn't know what `subset_data` actually is (a `DataFrame`, I'm assuming). Remember, Sublime isn't an IDE, and even though Anaconda is a great help, it can only do so much with the tools it has to work with.